# In how many ways can we write $n$ as a sum of positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we write $n$ as a sum of positive integers, where the order does not matter?

For example, 5 can be written as:

1+1+1+1+1

1+2+1+1 (This would be the same as 2+1+1+1.)

1+3+1

1+4

5

2+3

1+2+2

So, there are 7 ways (assuming I didn't miss anything!). How can we generalize this for any natural number $n$?

Answer (score 5):

These are called integer partitions, and there are a lot of fun combinatorics that goes along with them. If we let $p(n)$ denote the number of integer partitions of $n$, the generating function is given by

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p(n) x^n = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^j} $$

it's not too hard to convince yourself this is correct: the product on the right can be seen as

$$(1+x^{1\cdot1}+x^{2\cdot1}+x^{3 \cdot 1}+\dots)(1+x^{1\cdot2}+x^{2\cdot2}+x^{3\cdot 2}+\dots)(1+x^{1\cdot3}+x^{2\cdot3}+x^{3\cdot3}+\dots)\dots$$

so for example if we look at how one might get $x^5$:

- $x^{1\cdot5} \iff 5$
- $x^{1\cdot4} x^{1\cdot1} \iff 4 + 1$
- $ x^{1\cdot3}x^{1\cdot2} \iff 3 + 2$
- $ x^{1\cdot3}x^{2\cdot1} \iff 3 + 1 + 1$
- $ x^{2\cdot2}x^{1\cdot1} \iff 2 + 2 + 1$
- $ x^{1\cdot2}x^{3\cdot1} \iff 2 + 1 + 1 + 1$
- $ x^{5\cdot1} \iff 1 +1+1+ 1 + 1$

and so $p(5) = 7$, as you enumerated.

Unfortunately there's no nice formula for this, but asymptotically we have

$$p(n) \sim \frac{e^{\sqrt n \,c}}{4\sqrt 3 \,n},$$

where $ c = \sqrt \frac{2}{3} \pi$. This is harder to prove, but I believe it is due to Hardy and Ramanujan.

[Here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028998729) is the most straightforward proof I could find, though it uses some results from Complex Analysis.

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0002171v1.pdf) is a proof using only real analysis, but the result is slightly weaker.

Comment: You should probably make it more clear that the asymptotic is only approximately true, say by using $\sim$ or $\approx$ instead of $=$.

Comment: Ah thank you! Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: There's actually now an exact formula for the partition function (probably not "nice" at the level the OP might be expecting) thanks to recent work of Bruinier and Ono!

Comment: Is this the paper you're referring to? http://www.aimath.org/news/partition/brunier-ono.pdf

Comment: It is indeed, thanks :)

Comment: It'll take me some work to understand it too! What background is necessary for this paper?

Comment: I can't claim to understand even 20% of the paper, but it certainly requires a good grounding in modular forms and Maass forms.  The formula itself is described in relatively simple terms, but again I wouldn't be familiar with the best practices for efficiently computing the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if there are $A_n$ ways to express $n$ as a sum of positive integers, $A_{n+1} = A_n + A_{(1,n-1)} + A_{(2,n-2)} + \cdots$, where $A_{(1,n)}$ is the number of ways to express $n$ as a sum of positive integers greater than $1$ (i.e. $2, 3, 4,$ etc.), $A_{(2,n)}$ is the number of ways to express $n$ as a sum of positive integers greater than $2$ (i.e. $3, 4, 5,$ etc.), etc.